# Merge array value also with Object.assign

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have an object like the following:

```
{
  '4123': [
    { name: 'John', age: '29' }
  ],
  '1514': [
    { name: 'Kelly', age: '25' }
  ]
}
```

And so:

```
{
  '4123': [
    { name: 'Peter', age: '53' }
  ],
  '567': [
    { name: 'Joost', age: '61' }
  ]
}
```

I used `Object.assign(json1, json2)` to try and achieve what I want and I got the following result:

```
{
  '4123': [
    { name: 'Peter', age: '53' }
  ],
  '567': [
    { name: 'Joost', age: '61' }
  ],
  '1514': [
    { name: 'Kelly', age: '25' }
  ]
}
```

But I need the result to be similar to this:

```
{
  '4123': [
    { name: 'John', age: '29' },
    { name: 'Peter', age: '53' }
  ],
  '567': [
    { name: 'Joost', age: '61' }
  ],
  '1514': [
    { name: 'Kelly', age: '25' }
  ]
}
```

Seems like I almost got it right. I think its rewriting the properties value with the newly merged value instead of pushing it to the array. How can I make it push the array values as well?

Answer (score 0):

`Object.assign` isn't the right tool here (but one can see how you got there), because you're just combining arrays (adding entries from an array into another), not merging objects by property name.

Instead, loop through the object containing the arrays you want to merge into the other object's arrays and use either `push` (to modify the other object's existing array) or `concat` (to produce a new array) to add the entries:

```js
const obj1 = {
  '4123': [
    { name: 'John', age: '29' }
  ],
  '1514': [
    { name: 'Kelly', age: '25' }
  ]
};
const obj2 = {
  '4123': [
    { name: 'Peter', age: '53' }
  ],
  '567': [
    { name: 'Joost', age: '61' }
  ]
};
// Object.keys returns an array of an object's string property names
for (const key of Object.keys(obj2)) {
  // See if obj1 also has this
  const other = obj1[key];
  if (other) {
    // Yes, append these entries to it
    other.push(...obj2[key]);
  }
}

console.log(obj1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

(If any of `obj1`'s arrays may contain entries with the same `name` as the corresponding `obj2`'s array, you'll have to decide what to do with the conflict.)

---

Your use of `Object.assign` suggests a modern environment, but if you need to support an ES5-only environment, we just use `var` instead of `const`, `forEach` instead of `for-of`, `other.push.apply(other, obj2[key]);` instead of spread notation, and a `function` function rather than an arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new function using `reduce()` method that will iterate through second object keys and merge it with first object.

```js
const obj1 = {"1514":[{"name":"Kelly","age":"25"}],"4123":[{"name":"John","age":"29"}]}
const obj2 = {"567":[{"name":"Joost","age":"61"}],"4123":[{"name":"Peter","age":"53"}]}

const merge = (o1, o2) => {
  return Object.keys(o2).reduce(function(r, e) {
    if (r[e]) r[e].push(...o2[e])
    else r[e] = o2[e]
    return r;
  }, o1)
}

console.log(merge(obj1, obj2))
```